# .bashrc equivalent for rails console?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bash, rails-console

When I'm using the [rails console](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html) I like having a `clear!` command along side the `reload!` command, so every time I launch the rails console I write

```
def clear!
   system('clear')
end
```

When I repeat behavior in my bash shell I add it to my `~/.bashrc` file.  Is there a similar way for me to do this for my rails console?

Comment: Just realized that `control`+`l` clears irb/rails console too, so don't use the redundant clear function in my example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a file in your home directory named `~/.irbrc`. Inside, define any functions or settings you want to be applied to your irb.

[Here's](http://dotfiles.org/~bogojoker/.irbrc) an example that explains what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with **[Pry](https://github.com/pry/pry)** if you use that instead of irb. You can configure custom commands in a `~/.pryrc`

```
Pry.config.commands.command "clear!", "Clears the display" do |*args|
  system("clear")
end
```

- See [pry-rails](https://github.com/rweng/pry-rails)